# How to get location on each 200 meters in terminated state in ios

Tags: ios, location, cllocationmanager, suspend

i am trying to get user's location in app's terminated state. i am doing this by `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` but it's giving location after 3km or after 5 min. so can't create a route properly. please guide me how to do this.

```
 if (_anotherLocationManager)
    [_anotherLocationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

self.anotherLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
_anotherLocationManager.delegate = self;
_anotherLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
_anotherLocationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation;

if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    [_anotherLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
[_anotherLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

Comment: Add your code at least... otherwise it's hard to figure it out!

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440190/ios-startmonitoringsignificantlocationchanges-sometimes-breaks-monitoring

Answer (score 0):

I solved my query myself...

Create a locationManager object and alloc it like this

```
 self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init]; // initializing locationManager
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation; // setting the accuracy
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates)]) {
    [self.locationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates: YES];
}

self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 20.0;

[self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

self.locationManager.activityType=CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = YES;

self.locationManager.delegate = self;
```

Now set location manager delegate method.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
{
    if (newLocation.speed>7){
      // here you got location, i settled speed 7 for my convenience.  
    }

    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy) {
        //Desired location Found
        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation ];
    }
}
```

You must have to write this `stopUpdatingLocation`, else your battery consumption will increase so high.

Comment: incorrect, the documentations states different: "After returning a current location fix, the receiver generates update events only when a significant change in the user’s location is detected. It does not rely on the value in the distanceFilter property to generate events."

Answer (score 0):

Use the Geofencing to achieve the same.

- Create a Geofence of 200mtr radius.
- By default, notifyOnExit would be true
- Implement the delegate `didExitRegion` of LocationManager
- For termination state, the app would be lunched with `UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.location` in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
- Create an instance of Location Manager object on location launch key, you obtain the region at which the location exited and keep creating the 200mtr fence on every exit.

Answer (score -1):

You're not going to get 200 meter granularity or continuous tracking with significant location monitoring.

Have you seen these notes in the docs:

> The significant-change location service delivers updates only when
>   there has been a significant change in the device’s location, such as
>   500 meters or more.
>
> If GPS-level accuracy isn’t critical for your app and you don’t need
>   continuous tracking, you can use the significant-change location
>   service.

Comment: i have read it. but app is not working even in 500 , its working more than 3 km. or 10 min.